# Translation on Kindle

Tags: kindle

We work with teenagers and adults diagnosed with dyslexia who practise reading using a kindle.

When they come to a word they have difficulty reading they use the 'translation' function simply to have the word read aloud.

When they highlight a word on a Kindle the user has 3 choices which are
:.

Dictionary - Wikipedia - Translate

And they appear in that order, i.e. Translate is never the first choice - you have to scroll to get it.

Is it possible

1. To change the order so that 'Translate' appears as the first choice.

or

2. Can you delete both Dictionary and Wikipedia and only have the Translate option?.

Comment: Don't think either of that is possible since there is no option to customize the UI.